# How to hide navigation bar from popover view in iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios6, xcode4.5, uipopovercontroller

I have one application that presents popover view. All the things work well, but I am not able to hide navigation bar from popover view.

I also searched many things, I'm but not getting any solutions.

This question may be duplication of existing popover related question, but I am not getting from that so please help.

Comment: have u tried this     self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden=TRUE;

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar appears only when there is a `UINavigationController` instance as the popover contents. Use a different controller or hide the navigation bar on the controller itself.